# Set a TextView text size according to the height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I create a layout for `dailpad` using `LinearLayout` and I divided the number by using `layout_weight`.

```
 <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_digitOne"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum=".9">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/digit_one"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".6"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="#e03a2f2d"
                        android:textSize="45sp"
                        android:text="1"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".2"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>
```

Here for the Digit `one` in the TextView I set the size for Text by 45sp.but when got the small screen because of text size specify in the layout, the layout is distroying.

Is it possible according to `TextView layout_height can set the textSize`

Can anyone give me an idea
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use styles, then you can have separate folders "values" (default) "values-hdpi" (high density) "values-mdpi" (medium density) and so on and put your style file with correct textSize values in each folder as needed.

For example,

```
res/values/dimens.xml

res/values-small/dimens.xml

res/values-normal/dimens.xml

res/values-large/dimens.xml

res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml
```

Now specify the values you desire to keep in different XML file. 
Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="text_size">18sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

By doing this it will fetch the correct XML according to your screen size and set the TextSize mentioned in that XML.

Answer (score 2):

You need make a different layouts or use that library,

https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Answer (score 0):

Use dimens.xml to control the size of `TextView` according to device size. You can do this by setting different size of Text in different versions of dimens.xml and then reference the size in layout xml instead of directly hardcoding it.

```
<TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/<nameOfTextSizeInDimens>"
                    android:text=""/>
```